# Creating a link using Tiptap

Tags: reactjs, tiptap

When creating a link in Tiptap (react) I want to set the highlighted text as a link, and then let the user keep typing on the same link as normal text.

Just like [this](https://stackoverflow.com) is.

However using their demo their command is:

`editor.chain().focus().extendMarkRange('link').setLink({ href, target: '_blank' }).run()`

However, when the user then keeps typing, all of that text is also rendered as a link. Which results in this:

just like [this is.](https://www.google.com)

I have been through their documentation but can't seem to find a command that will remove the link mark from future text, without also removing it from the link I have just added.

One thing I thought might work is inserting a space after the text and then removing the mark, however this creates a new line.

Any help greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Turned out to be a simple answer. Just had to change the Link extension from Tiptap

```
Link.extend({
  inclusive: false
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've spent like an hour and a half trying to figure this out